# Update multiple columns in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Helper,

I'm having two table as users and addresses. I have saved multiple addresses for a user. Now I wanna update one of the users address. Is there any single query for update. I'm getting every input as array.

```
*users table*
id | name
1  | Mr.X

 *addresses table*
    id | user_id | city | state |country
    1  |   1     | XXX  | YYY   | ZZZ
    2  |   1     | AAA  | BBB   | CCC
```

I wanna change like this,

```
 *addresses table*
id | user_id | city | state |country
1  |   1     | XXX  | SSS   | ZZZ
2  |   1     | AAA  | BBB   | CCC
```

I have tried below code, but it do change in all columns.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){   //$id is users table id
   foreach($request->city as $key => $v) {
        $user->addresses()->where('user_id', '$id')->update([   //$user->addresses() is one to many relation
            'city' => $v,
            'state' => $request->state[$key],
            'country' => $request->country[$key]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're having same `user_id` and it'll update a record where `user_id = 1`, Also you are using `'$id'` and i think it should be `$id`. Remove `''` quote!

Comment: Check if using '$id' is the problem. Variables should not be in simple quotes

Comment: you need to update addresses table based on it's id make sure $id is addresses table record id not the user_id

Comment: Ya, as I mentioned in the question, I'm storing two addresses for single user and wanna update one of the addresses

Comment: I don't want to give multiple user_id for a same user

Comment: Where is `$user` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will update every entry of the user in the table. Since you have an "id" column (which I believe is the PK) in the address table. I think you can make use of it. You can retrieve it using the existing values.
For eg: If you want to update the first row

```
    $address = \DB::table("address")->where("city",=,"xxx")->where("country","=","zzz")->where('user_id',=,$id)->first();
\DB::table("address)->find($address->id)->update(["state"=>"new value"]);
```

Or else you can do

```
\DB::table("address")->where("city",=,"xxx")->where("country","=","zzz")->where('user_id',=,$id)->update(["state"=>"new value"]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way; I believe this will solve your problem..

You need to pass `$addressId` as a parameter if you do not wish to update all of the addresses. This will update only the address of the given `$addressId` and rest of the addresses will not be affected.

```
/**
 * Update the users address of the given user id and address id.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request  The form data
 * @param  integer  $userId  The id of the user
 * @param  integer  $addressId  The id of address
 *
 * @return
 */
public function update(Request $request, $userId, $addressId)
{
    $user = User::with('addresses')->find($userId);
    if (! $user) {
        // return failure message of user not found...
    }

    $address = $user->addresses->where('id', $addressId)->first();

    if (! $address) {
        // return failure message and redirect...
    }

    $address->update($request->all());

    // return success message and redirect...
}
```